# Neo4j Cypher query to find node IDs for array of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a collection/array of nodes for which I want to find the nodeID for every node in the array. Something like this -

Foreach node in [Nodes]
return ID(node)

Comment: Looks like this one should work - `with ["abc","bcdfg","ced"] as names  unwind names as name return name , length(name)`

Comment: `["abc","bcdfg","ced"]` are node lables or what else?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you asked you'd do:

```
UNWIND ["abc", "def"] as val
MATCH (n:<yourlabel> {Value: val}) //Where 'Value' is your property
RETURN ID(n)
```

This gets you the Neo4j ID of your nodes, but you should **not** use this to do anything with unless you really have good cause to.

Comment: ...you mentioned we should not use this unless there is good cause of using it..can you please explain me why its not advisable to use something like?

Comment: The Neo4j ID is volatile - if you delete a node, the ID can be used again, so if you were querying by ID you could get something different. It's much better to use your own form of ID, be it an `int` or something more unique like a `GUID`, as *you* then control the use of it.